# How can i pass data to a modal component in Vuejs. my issue is that it doest not show up at all on the browser

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this is the modal

```
<template>
    <div>
         <transition name="modal" id="modal-template">
             <div class="modal-mask" >
                 <div class="modal-wrapper">
                     <div class="modal-container" >
                         <div class="modal-header">
                             <slot name="header">
                             </slot>
                         </div>
                         <div class="modal-body" >
                             <slot name="body">
                                 <h4 style="font-size:18px" class="order-title">
                                     <!-- Productname  -->
                                     <h4 >{{items.name}}</h4>/<!-- this is not showing -->
                                 </h4> 
                              </slot>               
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </transition>
      </div>               
</template>
```

The PARENT VIEW..

```
<template>
    <div  class="card">
        <div  v-bind:key="item.item_id" v-for="item in items" class="card-body">
        <!--here i add the v-for to loop through the data but its undefined or empty -->
            <div class="row product-order">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                    <h4 >{{ item.name }}</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="image-container">
                            <div class="col-2 product-info-product-image">
                                 <div v-bind:key="items.item_id" v-for="items in item_id">
                                     <OrderdetailModal
                            v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false"/>
                            </div>
                            <img
                                @click="goToProductinfo(item.item_id)"
                                class="center product-info-product-image"
                                :src="item.product_image"
                             />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import OrderdetailModal from '../components/Orderdetail';
//beginning of data an methods calls

export default 
{
    name:"Product",
    components:{
        OrderdetailModal
    },
    data () {//here is the data of the parent view
        return {
            item_id:[],
            showModal: false
        }
    },
    methods:{
        goToProductinfo(item_id)
        {  //here is the function that fetch the data.
            this.getProductinfo(item_id);//fetches data and set item_id to response
             this.showModal = true;//sets modal to true
         }
         //end of all methods
         //these function should work perfectly 
     }
}
               //end of export default
</script>
//end of code
```

Comment: Inisde your parent vue component there a `div` not closed? Please reformat your code correctly & look for any code typos you have made.

Comment: i just did bu i know that won't solve it